# Помогите найти ошибку в коде C++

Tags: c++

Код записывает в массив остатки от деления, что бы перевести число в двоичную систему. Но необходимо "перевернуть" числа.

```css
while (n!=0) 
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        bin_n[i]=n%2; 
        n = n/2;  
        kol=kol+1; 
        cout<<bin_n[i]; 
    } 
}
```

Если выводить массив после цикла, то он выводится не правильно.

```
for (int i=0; i<kol; i++) 
{
     cout<<bin_n[i];
}
```

Comment: Например: число 10. В первом цикле выводится 0101, но во втором цикле выводит 1100.

Comment: Где может быть ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно, не очень понимаю, зачем вам вообще внутренний цикл

```
kol = 0;
while (n!=0) 
{ 
        bin_n[kol]=n%2; 
        n = n/2;  
        cout<<bin_n[kol];
        kol++;  
}
```

А еще, чтобы при выводе перевернуть число стоит его выводить не подряд

```
for (int i=kol-1; i>=0; i--) 
{
     cout<<bin_n[i];
}
```